# help with pgfplot a .csv data file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So i'm really new to pgfplot, a couple of hours now and I'm trying to build a graph such as this:

[image: just a chart]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3yq97oc9rwmthh/mcgreedy.csv?dl=0
Here is the .csv file!

x-axis is the experiment trial
y-axis has 2 different algorithms and the score they yield at each trial

I'm getting some errors that have to do with my attempt of plotting a simple line {x+1} which for now, i'm only trying to do to get a visualisation of what I'm doing

Thanks everyone!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 width=10cm,
  grid = major,
  grid style = {dashed, gray!30},     
  xmin = 0,
  ymin = 0,
  xmax = 105,
  ymax = 280,     
  /pgfplots/xtick = {0,5,...,100},
   axis background/.style = {fill=white},
    ylabel = {Trial Number},
    xlabel = {Score},
    tick align = outside,
   ]   
  \addplot table {mcgreedy.csv}
  %\addplot[domain=0:100, red, thick] ({x+1});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome! What does `mcgreedy.csv` look like? Which errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing a semicolon at the end of the `\addplot` line`. And by default just one plot is added from a file, so you need two, one for each series.

Some other comments:

- If you want the legend entries displayed in a row, as in your screenshot, add `legend columns=-1`.
- I think there should be some more space between the `xticklabels`. You can for example reduce the font size a bit (`ticklabel style={font=\small}`), increase the width of the axis (if there's room), or have fewer ticks. A tick every 10 points may be enough here.
- Note that you don't need `/pgfplots/` before `xtick`.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots,showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=0.95\linewidth,
  height=0.6\linewidth,
  grid = major,
  grid style = {dashed, gray!30},     
  xmin = 0,
  ymin = 0,
  xmax = 105,
  ymax = 280,     
  xtick = {0,10,...,100},
  ylabel = {Trial Number},
  xlabel = {Score},
  tick align = outside,
  legend pos=south east,
  legend columns=-1
   ]   
  \addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {mcgreedy.csv};
  \addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {mcgreedy.csv};

  \legend{ECTS, E.G.}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=0.95\linewidth,
  height=0.6\linewidth,
  grid = major,
  grid style = {dashed, gray!30},     
  xmin = 0,
  ymin = 0,
  xmax = 105,
  ymax = 280,     
  xtick = {0,5,...,100},
  ticklabel style={font=\small},
  ylabel = {Trial Number},
  xlabel = {Score},
  tick align = outside,
  legend pos=south east,
  legend columns=-1
   ]   
  \addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {mcgreedy.csv};
  \addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {mcgreedy.csv};

  \legend{ECTS, E.G.}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

(The frame shows the text area, generated by the `showframe` package.)
[image]